# Allow tags to be favorited from the tags page

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

As a new user on an SE site, if I want to choose my favorite tags for the first time (for example, picking the languages I know on Stack Overflow), I have to have some idea of which tags exist before editing the Favorite Tags box, or make a guess when typing and hope something autocompletes. When doing this, there is no way to see basic tag information beyond the number of posts that exist with that tag.

One way I would expect to be able to favorite tags would be by clicking the "Tags" button at the top of the screen (go figure), and having some option to favorite a tag without leaving the page. Mousing over a tag displays an info box with links for email subscription and RSS feed, but no favorite option.

Implementing this would correct the workflow described above to the following:

1. Click "Tags" (https://stackoverflow.com/tags)
2. Click to favorite the most popular tags I am interested in
3. Type a few characters in the filter box to narrow down to less popular tags, repeat step 2.

**Workaround:** Use two windows to browse and filter tags in one and add favorites in another.

I think this would greatly improve the experience for users who are new to favorite tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can already do this. Just hover over the tag you're interested in to get the black popup, then click on the star in the top left corner of that box to toggle between favorite, ignored, and off. This also works from question lists and directly on a question page.

Comment: Good grief. That never occurred to me. Every site has a different visual vocabulary for "favorite," it seems.